# Bash script, returns awk: can't open file ~/.ssh/config

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, tilde-expansion

I'm able to awk this file directly from the command line but when I try to use it from my script it breaks. Not sure why. Heres my script

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh_config_path="~/.ssh/config"

echo -n "Enter the username of the account you'd like to switch to > "
read username


awk '
  !x{x=sub(/github-secondary/,"github.com")}
  !y{y=sub(/github\.com/,"github-secondary")}
  1' $ssh_config_path
```

Comment: Where do you use `$username` from read command?

Comment: havent used it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In quotes bash does not expand `~`. I suggest to use `$HOME`:

```
ssh_config_path="$HOME/.ssh/config"
```

Comment: Or just leave out the quotes.