# Can't use folder path with tilde in rmdir

Tags: bash, macos, path, filenames, tilde-expansion

I need to be able to remove a directory that is relative to the Documents folder of any user's system.

```
rmdir: ~/Documents/Folder: No such file or directory
```

If I manually enter the expanded path (/Users/ricky/Documents/Folder), it works fine.

I thought bash automatically expanded the tilde at the beginning of paths?

**Update:**

After trying a bunch of different approaches as recommended, I'm pretty confident now that the issue is with how I'm storing the path. I'm getting the path from a text file which I read line by line:

```
...
export_folder_path="$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d=)"
...

echo $export_folder_path
rmdir $export_folder_path
rmdir "$HOME/Documents/Folder\ 1"
```

This outputs the following:

```
$HOME/Documents/Folder\ 1
rmdir: $HOME/Documents/Folder\ 1: No such file or directory
rmdir: /Users/ricky/Documents/Folder\ 1: Directory not empty (This is actually what I want)
```

I can't work out what the difference between my manually typing the export path and using the variable. Why is the variable refusing to expand `$HOME`? I have tried many variations of adding quotations with no luck.

Comment: What does `realpath -m ~/Documents/Folder` output?

Comment: @sschuberth I don't seem to have a program called realpath?

Comment: What are you running? From the path it looks like you're running Bash under Windows. If so, what Bash? Cygwin? MSYS(2)? Git for Windows? Linux subsystem under Windows 10?

Comment: @sschuberth I'm on macOS 10.12.2

Comment: bash does not expand `~` if the string is in single or double quotation marks.

Comment: @Cyrus What am I to do if my path has a space in it then?

Comment: Escape the space with a backslash.

Comment: Use `~/"Documents/Folder"` or `"$HOME/Documents/Folder"`.

Comment: See: [Bash script, returns awk: can't open file ~/.ssh/config](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40685676/3776858)

Answer (score 3):

Tilde expansion doesn't work in all cases. You can instead use the `HOME` variable:

```
rmdir $HOME/Documents/Folder
```

From [bash manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> Tilde Expansion  If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character
>   ('~'), all of the characters preceding the first unquoted slash (or
>   all characters, if  there is no unquoted slash) are considered a
>   tilde-prefix.  If none  of the characters in the tilde-prefix are
>   quoted, the characters in  the tilde-prefix following the tilde are
>   treated as a possible login  name.  If this login name is the null
>   string, the tilde is replaced  with the value of the shell parameter
>   HOME.  If HOME is unset, the  home directory of the user executing the
>   shell is substituted  instead.  Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is
>   replaced with the home  directory associated with the specified login
>   name.
>
> If the tilde-prefix is a '~+', the value of the shell variable PWD 
>   replaces the tilde-prefix.  If the tilde-prefix is a '~-', the value 
>   of the shell variable OLDPWD, if it is set, is substituted.  If the 
>   characters following the tilde in the tilde-prefix consist of a 
>   number N, optionally prefixed by a '+' or a '-', the tilde-prefix is 
>   replaced with the corresponding element from the directory st, as  it
>   would be displayed by the dirs builtin invoked with the tilde-  prefix
>   as an argument.  If the characters following the tilde in the 
>   tilde-prefix consist of a number without a leading '+' or '-', '+' is 
>   assumed.
>
> If the login name is invalid, or the tilde expansion fails, the word 
>   is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks @usr, I've updated my question to add some further detail on why it still isn't working.

Comment: Great. `$HOME` works perfectly that replaces the need of `~` in this case. Thanks